# problem about Parameter transfer of jsonpath

Tags: python, jsonpath

I am running a code like below, but it's not what I want. **real_path** is defined at def check, so it's static.

```
#code before change
def check(path):
    with open(path,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        file=json.load(f)
    real_path='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Local Settings\\Temp\\5.exe'
    call = jsonpath(file,"$.behavior.processes[?(@.process_path==real_path)].calls[?(@.category=='network')]")
    print(call)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path="C:/users/hdl/Desktop/2min/2-5.json"
    #real_path = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Local Settings\\Temp\\5.exe'
    check(path)
```

Then I have changed like below, I have defined the real_path at main, thus it has worked.

```
def check(path):
    with open(path,'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        file=json.load(f)
    #real_path='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Local Settings\\Temp\\5.exe'
    call = jsonpath(file,"$.behavior.processes[?(@.process_path==real_path)].calls[?(@.category=='network')]")
    print(call)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path="C:/users/hdl/Desktop/2min/2-5.json"
    real_path = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Local Settings\\Temp\\5.exe'
    check(path)
```

Does somebody know why?

What if I want to define at def check, what should I do?

Comment: I don't want use gloabal.Because I want to make it concurrency.

Comment: if you don't want global variable then send it as another parameter `def check(path, real_path):`

Comment: Sorry,I didn't make it clear.Parameter:real_path is Dynamic acquisition .I give it a Fixed value here for simplify.But it's a value get from a function.So if I do as you  say,I need a lock when I make it concurrency.

Comment: it doesn't mattter if you have fixed or dynamic - first generate `real_path` and later send as second parameter. And you don't have to lock it if you first generate all `real_path` and later run `check()` (with different `real_path`) using concurrency

Comment: Thanks a lot.Unfortunately,I get differnt real_path by read different file.So I can't get all real_path at first.

Comment: I still don't understand - what is the problem tot get `real_path = some_function()` and later `def check(path, real_path):`. And with current code there is no solution because it would need all details.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I confused the concept of concurrency.Thanks for your help again.